# How to print method name of dynamically assigned function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dynamic

When I run the following piece of code, only the print statements in the method, which I have dynamically assigned to the class "Test"  only return "my_unique_method_name".

**How to print the method name I have given it?** (Which is "wizardry" in the method—see "Expected Output" below.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import inspect

class Test:
    pass

def my_unique_method_name(self):
    print(inspect.stack()[0][3])
    print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name)
    print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)

Test.wizardry = my_unique_method_name
t = Test()
t.wizardry()
```

**Current Output**

```
my_unique_method_name
my_unique_method_name
my_unique_method_name
```

**Expected Output**

```
wizardry
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function *is* "my_unique_method_name" - the function is an object with a property which is its name.
`Test.wizardy` is just a variable, and its name is unrelated to the function which is its value.

It's the same siutation as these:

```
>>> def unique(): pass
...
>>> unique
<function unique at 0x0000000002CA4F28>
>>> unique.__name__
'unique'
>>> f = unique
>>> f.__name__
'unique'
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.g = unique
>>> a.g
<function unique at 0x0000000002CA4F28>
>>> a.g.__name__
'unique'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by examining the contents of `self.__class__.__dict__`:

```
class Test:
    pass

def my_unique_method_name(self):
    for k, v in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
        if v == my_unique_method_name:
            print(k)
            break  # Assume there's only one.


Test.wizardry = my_unique_method_name
t = Test()
t.wizardry()  # -> wizardry
```

Here's a more generic (and thus reusable) way of doing it that doesn't require the function assigned to do anything special—it's also likely to be a little faster since there's no `for` loop:

```
from functools import wraps

class Test:
    pass

def my_unique_method_name(self):
    pass

def assign_function_to_method(func, cls, name):
    @wraps(func)  # Optional (but recommended).
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print(name)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    setattr(cls, name, wrapped)


assign_function_to_method(my_unique_method_name, Test, 'wizardry')
t = Test()
t.wizardry()  # -> wizardry
```

Either approach works in both Python 2 and 3.